# Teradata - Return records added since first of last month, but before

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata 14, with the Teradata 13 client.

I want to pull all records from a table (it contains a time stamp), for the previous month.
Something like:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, DATECOL
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATECOL >= FIRST_OF_LAST_MONTH
    AND DATECOL IS < FIRST_OF_THIS_MONTH
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm new to Teradata.

Comment: First of month based on current date ?

Comment: Yes, I want to run it on the 1st or 2nd of each month, to pull the previous month's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, DATECOL
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATECOL >= ADD_MONTHS (CURRENT_DATE -EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1 , -1)
AND DATECOL < CURRENT_DATE -EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1
```

or you might just want to enter date

```
>=DATE '2014-05-01'
< DATE '2014-04-01'
```

Comment: This can be further optimized :-)  `DATECOL BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (CURRENT_DATE - (EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1), -1) AND CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)`